# Jess -> How to change execution between modules freely?

Tags: module, jess

I'm working on a game project where I have 3 modules in Jess. The MAIN module, then an Environment module and a Movement module.

I've been trying to change execution between these 3 modules with no success. My idea is the following:

1. Execute the MAIN Module, firing a rule using the initial-fact. Give focus to Environment Module first and then the Movement Module
2. Execute the rules from the Environment Module
3. Execute the rules from the Movement Module
4. Repeat until Halt

I've been using the (focus) function in the MAIN Module (focus Environment Movement), it then executes the Environment Module correctly and goes to the Movement Module. Again, this one also executes correctly.

I then give focus to the MAIN Module (I have also tried to assert the initial-fact again to try to force the initial rule to fire. However, it doesn't work).

Independently of what I do, it does not execute the MAIN Module again.

Could anyone please give me some insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

A given rule will fire only once for a given match, regardless of module focus. If you need the rules in MAIN to fire again, you need to remove the initial conditions that led them to fire in the first place, and then recreate them. This may be as simple as retracting `(initial-fact)` and then reasserting it. The retracting part is important!